# FULLTEXT search MySQL not working as expected

Tags: mysql

According to mysql docs it says that adding the + operator in boolean search would require the search to have the word.

I used this query, but it's resulting a row which contains only 1 of the words.
It's resulting a row which contains "bonne" but the word "bella" is not in it. 
I am 100% sure I added UFLLTEXT to the column I'm searching for.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
SELECT article_title,MATCH(article_title) AGAINST ("+bonne +bella" IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance 
        FROM feed_list WHERE MATCH(article_title) AGAINST ("+bonne +bella" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

table created like this

```
CREATE TABLE `feed_list` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `article_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `article_title` (`article_title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: You might want to check your stop word list.  The language does not appear to be English, and perhaps "bella" is not being indexed at all.

Comment: my list contains the default out of the box list. Shouldn't it return nothing anyway then?

Comment: @renevdkooi I've created db with your table and add some raw data. using YOUR query I've got result you are looking for. so now it comes to the data. show us please the raw data you have in your table, and result records selected by your query please

Comment: Really weird, i've recreated the table and now it does work.... :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
SELECT article_title,
    MATCH(article_title) AGAINST ("+bonne +bella" IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevance
FROM feed_list 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

You can add `LIMIT` if you don't want get too many records.

Comment: still giving me rows with bella in it (relevance being 1), so this only made it worse as i get all results back already

Comment: so you want to get records where both words presented? and follows in this order?

Comment: dont care about order, but both words must be in it. Now i'm getting either word in it (which in my understanding would be without the + operator) Adding the + sign doesn't do as expected

Comment: am I mistaken that this works that the + sign will add +1 to the relevance? Meaning it will still return both but relevance will go up?